# Raise event from multiple worker threads?

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, service, thread-safety

Using C# to create a windows service application. I have a main object that creates worker threads to periodically conduct various tasks.  Each worker completes a specific task, waits for a time, then repeats.

If one of those tasks should fail, I want that thread to alert the main to log that a task failed and then to exit.

I had thought about using a ManualResetEvent where Set would be called from each worker (and main would loop on checking it).  Problem is, multiple workers could fail simultaneously and attempt to Set() the event at the same time.

Is there a thread-safe way to handle alerting from multiple worker threads?  Only one alert is required, I don't need to handle any more than the first one received.

Comment: The use of TPL and `Task` objects would be ideal for this scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/task-parallel-library/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't use [Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) in your Setter / Event handler?

```
private static readonly object Locker = new object();
private bool _closing = false;

private void YourErrorHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(!_closing)
       lock (Locker)
          if(!_closing)
          {
              _closing = true;
              //What ever you need to do here
          }
}
```

If you need cross process sync, you will need to use Mutex or something else. But hope you get the idea

Comment: Accepting this answer as it seems the most correct.  I was a bit confused by [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37474/Threadsafe-Events) which was going on at great length to explain how one cannot use events with threads and ensure safety... but so long as I never unsubscribe, I imagine I'd never have a problem to worry about.  That said, I also just found out that I have a Linux box on which to run this app, so I think I'm going to have to switch languages to C++ or perhaps learn python (what the original dev started to use but didn't get too far).  Thanks!

Comment: Thought about using mono for the one linux box, but I need to support logging to eventlog (and now syslog) as well as linking to winpcap or libpcap. At this point, I'm not sure which way to go.  LOL

Answer (score 0):

Once one of the threads fails, you want to shut down the whole thing, correct?  Once that happens, when you join all of the threads, you can check their status and report an error for each individual one that failed.  Something like:

```
while(eventNotSet) sleep();

foreach(thread)
{
  thread.Join();
  checkStatus(thread);
}
```